# Need to fetch the attribute values from the XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xslt-2.0

I have worked on generating the elements and attributes names along with output elements and attributes. Here I'm converting input xml to docbook xml by using Oxygen XML Editor 18.0.

I'm having input xml like:

```
<Section1 id="1">
   <Section1Heading>Section 1</Section1Heading>
  <Section2 id="2">
    <Section2Heading>Heading</Section2Heading>
    <Para>other.</Para>
  </Section2>
</Section1>
```

XSL I'm having:

```
<xsl:template match="Section1">
   <sect1>
       <xsl:attribute name="label">
          <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </sect1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section1Heading | Section2Heading">
    <title>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </title>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Section2">
   <sect2>
      <xsl:attribute name="label">
         <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </sect2>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Para">
   <para>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </para>
</xsl:template>
```

Tried the XSL like below:

```
  <xsl:param name="field-sep" as="xs:string">,</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="line-sep" as="xs:string" select="'&#10;'"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('Input XML', $field-sep, 'Result XML')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$line-sep"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xsl:template[@match]">
    <xsl:value-of 
       select="for $pattern in tokenize(@match, '\s*\|\s*')
               return concat($pattern, $field-sep, node-name(current()/*[1]))"
       separator="{$line-sep}"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$line-sep"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Expected output would be:

```
Input XML,Result XML
Section1,sect1
@id,label
Section1Heading,title
Section2Heading,title
Section2,sect2
@id,label
Para,para
```

Comment: With `match="Section1"` I don't understand what `Section1/@id` would select, there are no nested `Section1` elements.

Comment: I have edited now. Please see

Comment: @MartinHonnen Order of expected output element and attributes also not an issue. If it reorder also not a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would produce the output you need, although it relies on your input XSLT having a very restricted structure (e.g. It assumes the `xsl:attribute` always contains `xsl:value-of`)

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:template[@match]">
  <xsl:variable name="current" select="." />
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(@match, '\s*\|\s*')">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., $field-sep, node-name($current/*[1]))" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$line-sep"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$current/*[1]/xsl:attribute">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(xsl:value-of[1]/@select, $field-sep, @name)" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$line-sep"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I'm getting the attributes like `label,@id`. But I need it as `@id,label`. Because input is @id and output is label

Comment: I've amended my answer to swap the two arguments in the relevant `concat` statement, so they should now be in the right order.